# Touchpad on Lenovo V330 (Thinkpad V Series) is not recognized

Tags: linux, touchpad, laptop

I've installed opensuse 42.3 on my new Lenovo V330, but whatever I do, the touchpad is not recognized by Linux. I've updated the Kernel to 4.15.7, tried to install tumbleweed, which brought the same result.
I can't even figure out which Touchpad is built into the Notebook (Elantech or Synaptics).
There is an Unclaimed USB device (Synaptics) listed in lshw, but i think this is the Fingerprint reader. I suspect the built in Touchpad is an Elantech device connected via I²C but that may be totally incorrect.

Comment: I got my touchpad to work on my Lenovo V330 using Ubuntu 18.04 by upgrading to Linux 4.18.3 (I used UKUU https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu to do this).

Answer (score 1):

My Lenovo v330 14IKB has an Elantech I2C Touchpad (ELAN0612) installed. It's working under Windows 10 Pro 64Bit with UEFI mode on and selected AHCI-Controller. Installed BIOSes were v2.02 and v4.01.

On Linux it's not found by xinput; `dmesg | grep -i elan` returns me:

```
i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0612:01: i2c-ELAN0612:01 supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
```

I'm running a fresh installation of **Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia** and tried it on kernel: **v4.16-rc7**, **v4.15.14**, **v4.13.0.37.42**.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working by adding the **ACPI ID** into `drivers/input/mouse/elan_i2c_core.c`

At the bottom of the file is a list of device ID's.

Mine is **ELAN0618**.

Now it works :)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but I don't understand your solution. Where exactly is this file located (I use Ubuntu 18.04)? I don't have a folder "drivers" in the root and also couldn't find this specific file using the search function.

Comment: Ok, I found a similar file, namely /lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/kernel/drives/input/mouse/elan_i2c.ko. But this seems to be compiled code and I don't see a source file. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Got it work under ubuntu 18.04 with adding ELAN0612 to `drivers/input/mouse/elan_i2c_core.c`.

Comment: You did what?  Did you just open the file and add the string `ELAN0612` at the end?  In a random spot? Could you elaborate?